# Cycle through divs - adding class to previous and next divs

Tags: jquery

Hopefully the title explains what I am looking to do, but possibly the code will explain it better. I am creating a slideshow/slider that sets up the next div by adding `loaded` class and marks the previous div as `last-active`. The current is then marked with `active`.

I have the following code that works to a point and is probably very inefficient but what I am looking to to is cycle through. So once `active` reaches div number 4 and the user clicks the button div number 1 becomes `active`, div number 4 becomes `last-active` and div number two becomes `loaded`.

I've reached a wall in terms of my current knowledge so an input at this point would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slide:first").addClass('active');
  $(".slide:first").next().addClass('loaded');
  
  $("button.change").click(function() {
    
    $('div.slide.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    $('div.slide.active').removeClass('loaded');
    $('div.slide.active').prev().addClass('last-active');
    $('div.slide.active').next().addClass('loaded');
    $('div.slide.last-active').prev().removeClass('last-active');
        
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
}


.active {
  background: red;
}

.last-active {
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.loaded {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.new {
  color: green;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
  
</div>
<button class="change">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code to retrieve all relevant elements like this:

```
var $active = $('.slide.active');
var $next = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 1) % $('.slide').length);
var $afterNext = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 2) % $('.slide').length);
```

This uses [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) combined with [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and a modulo to retrieve the currently active element and the two following items by their indexes.

You then simply have to add the desired CSS class to each of them. This also makes your code quite a lot easier to read in the process (personal opinion at least).

**Demo:**

```js
$(function () {
  $('.slide:first').addClass('active');
  $('.slide:eq(1)').addClass('loaded');

  $('button.change').on('click', function () {
    // Retrieve the currently active element, as well as next and next + 1 ones
    var $active = $('.slide.active');
    var $next = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 1) % $('.slide').length);
    var $afterNext = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 2) % $('.slide').length);

    // Remove all classes from slides
    $('.slide').removeClass('last-active active loaded');
    
    // Add the new classes
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.addClass('active');
    $afterNext.addClass('loaded');
  })
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }
.slide { width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block; background:#ddd; }
.active { background:red; }
.last-active { border:10px solid black; }
.loaded { border:10px solid green; }
.new { color:green; background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
</div>
<button class="change">Change</button>
```

(Note that I adjusted the rest of the code a tiny bit in the process.)

Comment: @Morgan, did it help?

Comment: yes, that was ideal thank you. And it made it more efficient. I had come across `eq()` in examples before but I am yet to use and understand it so I'll have a read into that method.